# R - How to use readline() with additional code after?

Tags: r, user-input, readline

Simple problem, but I can't find an answer that works anywhere.  When I use readline() (for example, as demonstrated here - http://www.rexamples.com/4/Reading%20user%20input) it works perfectly:

```
readinteger <- function()
{ 
n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
return(as.integer(n))
}
a <- print(readinteger())
```

However, if I add any code after this, readline() is skipped and the code just continues:

```
readinteger <- function()
{ 
n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
return(as.integer(n))
}
a <- print(readinteger())
b <- 7
```

Any solutions (and/or easier ways to get user input)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that as soon as `a <- print(readinteger())` is entered, it is evaluated, and `b <- 7` is interpreted as the input to `readline`. A solution is to wrap your code in a function or a block:

```
{
a <- print(readinteger())
b <- 7
}
```

By putting everything into a block, the whole block is read as code and only after, as it is evaluated, you will be prompted for an integer.

Comment: Thank you!  I had played with brackets, thinking it was the answer - but apparently didn't get it right.  One important thing I just figured out though - NOTHING can be after the last bracket.  Not even blank lines or empty space.  That's very important.

Comment: I seem to have run into a followup problem.  Using this method, I can only get the lest line of code returned from the bracketed section.  Example:

    `readinteger <- function()
    { 
    n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
    return(as.integer(n))
    }

    {
    a <- print(readinteger())
    b <- a + 10
    c <- 20
 
    a
    b
    c
    }`

In that code, the only results displayed are a (the user input) and c (the last line of code)

Comment: You'll need to use `print`.

Comment: :facepalm: I didn't even think that one through.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

put multiple outputs if processed by your function or the print function into "ONE object"

you name it: myOput <- list(abandoned.b,that.c)
             print(myoutput)